# Export to Excel in mvc4/razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a need to open a  grid in an Excel sheet. I have not been able to find a whole lot of resources for accomplishing this using MVC4/Razor. Can someone point me in the right direction and provide some useful tips?

Answer (score 1):

[razor](/questions/tagged/razor) has nothing to do with that. You just have to generate Excel file in controller. If you can use Excel 2007+, that go with Microsoft's own `Document.OpenXml`. If you can't, you'll have to make do with third-party.